# Tool to backup MS-SQL on shared hosting account

Tags: sql-server

I have about 3 MS-SQL databases on a shared hosting account. Their service is great but I can't perform a traditional database backup (can't save to server's hard drive).

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to automate this process on a nightly basis. I know I can use the Generate Scripts feature in Studio Manager but looking for something that's automated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can take the scripts from the SQL Server Management Studio, save them as a `.sql` file and then initiate them with `cmdsql` and a scheduled task. That's what a lot of people do to back up SQL Server Express, as it lacks a backup scheduler as well.